# Step back from app crash on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

Is there any feature that allow us step back from the crash and continue testing application?

Let say my application crashed when I touched some button, but I want to step back from this action and continue testing other parts without rerun simulator?

Comment: Not that I know of, once it crashes it kills the application and there is no way to continue. The best option is to use error handling to catch any errors/exceptions and handle them accordingly

Comment: yea sure, error handling it's ok, but sometimes you have unexpected behavior and roll back to previous step is a good bonus )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible. App crashes can have multiple reasons and it makes no sense to continue with compiled program code, when the app runs actually into a condition that is wrong.

For example you want to access a memory space with a pointer, but the memory space was not reserved and was released already for another application. How to continue here? Your program code cannot handle that or continue with that wrong condition. That's why the app will be crash when there is no `catch` mechanism that handles the unexpected behaviour / error. The machine protects itself.

Comment: yea I am sure that it's no an option for real devices, but for virtual devices such as iOS simulator there is no restriction I guess. Also I don't want to continue app with bad executed code or if smth bad happened when force unwrapping occurred for a nil object, I just want to step back and start over from the place I test when app has not been crashed yet. Like you can navigate through the threads and see which function called another one.

I am not sure if there is such solution, just wondering if there are some tricks for that